# Битрикс: добавить рейтинг пользователю

Tags: php, битрикс

При выполнении команды:

```
$arAddVote = array(
            "ENTITY_TYPE_ID"  =>  "USER",
            "ENTITY_ID"       =>  1,//ид рейтинга
            "VALUE"           =>  8,//значение рейтинга
            "USER_ID"         =>  2, //ид польз.
            "USER_IP"         =>  '127.0.0.1',
         );
         CRatings::AddRatingVote($arAddVote);
```

получаю ошибку:

```
Class: CRatings
File: *адрес сайта*/public_html/bitrix/modules/main/classes/mysql/ratings.php
Function: AddRatingVote
Line: 793
MySQL Query Error: UPDATE b_rating_voting SET `ACTIVE` = 'Y', `TOTAL_VOTES` = TOTAL_VOTES+1, `TOTAL_VALUE` = TOTAL_VALUE+NAN, `LAST_CALCULATED` = now(), `TOTAL_POSITIVE_VOTES` = TOTAL_POSITIVE_VOTES+1 WHERE ENTITY_TYPE_ID='USER' AND ENTITY_ID='1'[[1054] Unknown column 'NAN' in 'field list']
```

что может быть не так? (пользователь есть, рейтинг активен)

Comment: как видно из строки с ошибкой почему-то неверно считалось поле `VALUE`, хотя ему передано верное значение. поскольку хромает ядро, то лучше обратиться в поддержку Битрикса с таким же вопросом.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/zAN6QG4TB1LvkA
вот тут идет еще обчисление значения, вы какие-то из этих параметров меняли? они и могут давать вам `NaN`. Посмотрите, в порядки ли они у вас в таблице параметров http://joxi.ru/nAyJeoQHY9djZr